# How to get a diff between two states in Oracle database?

Tags: database, oracle, diff

I'm looking for a way to get a *diff* of two states (S1, S2) in a database (Oracle), to compare and see *what has changed* between these two states. Best would be to see what statements I would have to apply to the database in state one (S1) to transform it to state two (S2).

The two states are from the same database (schema) at different points in time (some small amount of time, not weeks).

I was thinking about doing something like a snapshot and compare - but how to make the snapshots and how to compare them in the best way ?

Edit: I'm looking for changes in the data (primarily) and if possible objects.

Comment: Are you looking for differences in data, objects (like new columns), or database configuration (v$parameter, etc)?

Comment: @JonHeller: I'm looking primarily for changes in the data, but if possible also objects (columns ) would be nice.

Answer (score 2):

This is one of those questions which are easy to state, and it seems the solution should be equally simple. Alas it is not.

The starting point is the data dictionary. From ALL_TABLES you can generate a set of statements like this:

```
select * from t1@dbstate2
minus
select * from t1@dbstate1
```

This will give you the set of rows that have been added or amended in dbstate2. You also need:

```
select * from t1@dbstate1
minus
select * from t1@dbstate2
```

This will give you the set of rows that have been deleted or amended in dbstate2. Obviously the amended ones will be included in the first set, it's the delta you need, which gives the deleted rows.

Except it's not that simple because:

- When a table has a surrogate primary key (populated by a sequence)
  then the primary key for the same record might have a different value
  in each database. So you should exclude such primary keys from the
  sets, which means you need to generated tailored projections for each
  table using ALL_TAB_COLS and ALL_CONSTRAINTS, and you may have to use
  your skill and judgement to figure out which queries need to exclude
  the primary key.
- Also, resolving foreign keys is problematic. If the foreign key is a
  surrogate key (or even if it isn't) you need to look up the
  referenced table to compare the meaning / description columns in the
  two databases. But of course, the reference data could have different
  state in the two databases, so you have to resolve that first.

Once you have a set of queries which identify the difference you are
   ready for the next stage: generating the appliance statements. There
   are two choices here: generating a set of INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE
   statements or generating a set of MERGE statements. MERGE has the
   advantage of idempotency but is a gnarly thing to generate. Probably
   go for the easier option.

Remember:

1. For INSERT and UPDATE statements exclude columns which are populated by triggers or are generated (identity, virtual columns).
2. For INSERT and UPDATE statements you will need to join to referenced tables for populating foreign keys on the basis of description columns (unless you have already synchronised the primary key columns of all foreign key tables).
3. So this means you need to apply changes in the order dictated by foreign key dependencies.
4. For DELETE statements you need to cascade foreign key deletions.
5. You may consider dropping foreign keys and maybe other constraints, but then you may be in a right pickle when you come to re-apply them only to discover you have you have constraint violations.
6. Use DML Error Logging to track errors in bulk operations. [Find out more](https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/dml-error-logging-10gr2).

If you need to manage change of schema objects too? Oh boy. You need to align the data structures first before you can even start doing the data comparison task. This is simpler than the contents, because it just  requires interrogating the data dictionary and generating DDL statements. Even so, you need to run `minus` queries on ALL_TABLES (perhaps even ALL_OBJECTS) to see whether there are tables added to or dropped from the target database. For tables which are present in both you need to query ALL_TAB_COLS to verify the columns - names, datatype, length and precision, and probably mandatory too.

Just synchronising schema structures is sufficiently complex that Oracle sell the capability as a chargeable extra to the Enterprise Edition license, [the Change Management Pack](http://www.oracle.com/us/products/enterprise-manager/change-management-pack-11g-ds-068451.pdf).

---

So, to confess. The above is a thought experiment. I have never done this. I doubt whether anybody ever has done this. For all but the most trivial of schemas generating DML to synchronise state is a monstrous exercise, which could take months to deliver (during which time the states of the two databases continue to diverge).

The straightforward solution? For a one-off exercise, Data Pump Export from S2, Data Pump Import into S1 using the `table_exists_action=REPLACE` option. [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-C9664F8C-19C5-4177-AC20-5682AEABA07F.htm#SUTIL936).

For ongoing data synchronisation Oracle offers a variety of replication solutions. Their recommended approach is [GoldenGate](https://www.oracle.com/middleware/data-integration/goldengate/index.html) but that's a separately licensed product so of course they recommend it :) Replication with Streams is deprecated in 12c but it's still there. [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/STRMS/release_changes.htm#STRMS1770).

The solution for synchronising schema structure is simply not to need it: store all the DDL scripts in a source control repository and always deploy from there.